# Odbc returns no query result

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I just connected with sqlserver using odbc, I am able to do some queries in console using isql, but when I am using php, odbc says connected only and there is no query result, please help, here's my script.

```
connect = odbc_connect("SERVER", "siap_999", "999") or die(odbc_error());
if ($connect) { 
    echo "MSSQL Connected !!! \n"; 
} else { 
    echo "MSSQL Connection Failed\n"; 
};

$strqry = "select * from Employee";
$result = odbc_exec($connect,$strqry);

while (odbc_fetch_row($result))
{   
    echo odbc_result($result, 4);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo odbc_num_rows($result);`? You can try it before `while`, if rows returned then the problem must be that you're trying to get field `4` that doesn't exist or is empty

Comment: Still no result bro, help me